# Change item color depending on the value range

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I got this `.item` box which has some value in it, by default it has background of grey. What I would like to achieve is to add the corresponding class to it depending on the value inside its `.item-value` tag. I have created a function `setItemColors` but it seems I'm missing something and I'm not sure if this is a good way to achieve it… Any ideas what could be a better solution? Thanks for any advice!

```js
function setItemColors() {
  // If 30 or under, set item class to item--blue
  if( $("#value").text() =< 30 ) {
      $(".item").addClass("item--blue");
    // If 31-79, set item class to item--yellow
  } else if ( $("#value").text() > 31 && <= 79 ) {
      $(".item").removeClass("item--blue");
      $(".item").addClass("item--red");
  }
  // If 80-100, set item class to item--red, if there is no value leave only .item class
  else if ( $("#value").text() > 80 && <= 100 ) {
      $(".item").removeClass("item--blue");
      $(".item").addClass("item--red");
  }
}

setItemColors();
```

```css
.item {
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: grey;
}

.item--blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.item--yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.item--red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="item">
  <span class="item-value" id="value">20</span>
  <span>%<span>
  <p>lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Your function contains invalid JavaScript, are you aware of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
if( $("#value").text() =< 30 ) {
```

and here:

```
} else if ( $("#value").text() > 31 && <= 79 ) {
```

and here:

```
else if ( $("#value").text() > 80 && <= 100 ) {
```

it should be:

```
if( $("#value").text() <= 30 ) {
```

and

```
} else if ( $("#value").text() > 31 && $("#value").text() <= 79 ) {
```

and

```
else if ( $("#value").text() > 80 && $("#value").text() <= 100 ) {
```

Also, don't forget to use `parseInt()` to convert the strings into ints for proper comparison on logic operations, as in:

```
if( parseInt($("#value").text()) <= 30 ) {
```

For robust code you should do some extra checks on the text values coming from the span. What you want to do if you get a NaN?

One last thing, your third if condition does not make much sense, since it keeps the red background - is that really what you want? (because if it is, then conditions 2 and 3 can be turn into single logic condition, right?)

Feel free to play with the fixed code here > https://jsfiddle.net/RuiCarvalho/dt3qrxpb/4/

Comment: Wow thanks for a great explanation. About the parseInt() -> not sure where exactly would I write that function..? And the third condition I probably got wrong, all I want is the added class to be "dominant", and if there is no value to just keep the .item class

Comment: I've edited the answer to help you on that ;) Glad to help. Feel free to accept the answer if it makes sense to you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There where multiple issue with your script which i have modified.

```js
function setItemColors() {
  // If 30 or under, set item class to item--blue
  if( $("#value").text() <= 30 ) {
      $(".item").addClass("item--blue");
    // If 31-79, set item class to item--yellow
  } else if ( $("#value").text() > 31 && $("#value").text() <= 79 ) {
      $(".item").removeClass("item--blue");
      $(".item").addClass("item--red");
  }
  // If 80-100, set item class to item--red, if there is no value leave only .item class
  else if ( $("#value").text() > 80 && $("#value").text() <= 100 ) {
      $(".item").removeClass("item--blue");
      $(".item").addClass("item--red");
  }
}

setItemColors();
```

```css
.item {
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: grey;
}

.item--blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.item--yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.item--red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <span class="item-value" id="value">20</span>
  <span>%<span>
  <p>lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```